# Better Way to Format Time as Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds in Excel?

Tags: excel, time, number-formatting

In Excel, I usually keep track of *time taken* by putting hours, minutes, and seconds into separate cells. I find that Excels built in date and time format has many quirks when it comes to adding and subtracting, which is why I avoid it.

Right now I have an Excel sheet keeping time of a repeated task like this:

```
|  H  |    I    |

| Min | Seconds |  
|  7  |   15    |
|  7  |   51    |
|  8  |   05    |
```

In cell `E5` I then put the total time, of the tasks, in seconds and convert it into days

```
=(SUM(H:H)*60+SUM(I:I))/60/60/24
```

Now I want the total from `E5` to be displayed in *days*, *hours*, *minutes*, and *seconds*. I could format `E5` as `d" days "h" hours "mm" min "s" s"`, but this does not work if the total time exceeds 30 days.

So what I have right now, in a different cell, is this formula:

```
=TRUNC(E5)&" days "
&TRUNC((E5-TRUNC(E5))*24)&" hours "
&TRUNC(((E5-TRUNC(E5))*24-TRUNC((E5-TRUNC(E5))*24))*60)& " min"
&TRUNC(((((E5-TRUNC(K5))*24-TRUNC((E5-TRUNC(E5))*24))*60)-
TRUNC((((E5-TRUNC(E5))*24-TRUNC((E5-TRUNC(E5))*24))*60)))*60)&" s"
```

(Note: The forumal is all on one line in Excel, I formatted it here so it's easier to read.)

The formula I have works and is accurate with any amount of time I use, but it's long and hard to follow. Is there any better way to do this?

(Keep in mind that I am working with cells formatted as numbers. There are not formatted as dates and they are not formatted as times.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the below image, I could not get your provided formula working (in E6) to any degree of certainty but I devised a formula coupling some worksheet functions with custom formatting masks that seems to work well.

[image: TRUNC days from datetime]

The formula in E7 is,

```
 =INT(E5)&TEXT(MOD(E5, 1), " \d\a\y\s h \h\r\s m \mi\n\s s \s\ec\s")
```

You cannot use both 0 and h in the same format string but you can remove the day portion and format for h, m and s. The backslashes in the format mask are escape characters and negate the need to double up quotes within a quoted string. The [INT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-4D0598D4-FAC0-4ED3-BFBC-BE6DC8544183) resolved the integer portion and the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-0CAF2C6C-891D-4A0B-B618-3B0D60296809) provides the decimal (aka Time) portion.

¹  <sub>I prefer the [INT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-4D0598D4-FAC0-4ED3-BFBC-BE6DC8544183) over the [TRUNC function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRUNC-function-8B86A64C-3127-43DB-BA14-AA5CEB292721) for removing the decimal portion of a number. This is strictly personal preference. In this case there is no difference. Even [ROUND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-C018C5D8-40FB-4053-90B1-B3E7F61A213C) could be used.</sub>

Comment: This worked great and is a much easier code to follow. One thing I noticed is there seems to be a limit to the number of days stored. The limit is at 134,217,727, I'm guessing that's the limit of "INT" variable in Excel? But, that's probably a far higher number of days than I'll ever need.